# how to create a sybase ASE readonly role

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I googled it but found nothing.

Is there a way to create a read only role ?

I mean, when a new object ( stored procedure, table,... ) is created, the "dbo" and "dba" can access it.

The dbo can do everything he wants with data model and content. the dba can do the same + server/security/... settings.

Is there some lower roles ? like:

1. "datamanager" a role that would automatically be granted insert/update/delete but no DDL ( ALTER ) **without the need of an explicit grant**
2. a "readonly role" ( even on newly created objects and  **without the need of an explicit grant**  )

**EDIT**

for sql server there is this:

https://chartio.com/docs/datasources/connections/details/sqluser

Comment: Sybase is a company, not a database, so you are going to have to specify which Sybase product you are using.

Comment: Sybase ASE ( Adaptive Server Enterprise )

Comment: Have you looked at using the 'guest' account? http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc31654.1550/html/sag1/X69386.htm

Comment: thanks i'll ask the DBA for that

Comment: i suggest creating a group in the specific database and only grant select access on any object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the roles in Sybase ASE, using **create role** command.

and grant the roles as per your wish to that role. it will work like a group, when you grant this role to someone will have only those privileges.